# Oracle SQL Date to Long and vice versa

Tags: sql, oracle, date, unix-timestamp

I have the following SQL Query which converts the long number to a date , i cannot convert the date back to the long number . kindly let me know your suggestion.

```
SELECT to_date((( 1432550197431912935  - POWER(2,60)) /POWER(2,44)) + to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) from dual
```

### Output

7/9/2013

```
select     TO_CHAR(((TO_DATE ('09-JUL-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') -to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY'))  * POWER(2,44) ) + POWER(2,60)) from dual
```

Output 
`1432549301782839296`

The long values are not the same.

Comment: Your immediate problem is precision; the date from the first select has a time component, which you're losing when you convert back; it should be `09-JUL-2013 01:13:19`. But as a timestamp it goes to `01:13:19.775670462`. How much precision do you need, and where has the `power` manipulation come from - what's the source for the number value?

Comment: @Alex: This logic was written a year back ,I was also confused with power manipulation and what is the significant of this.

Comment: @Alex: can u tell me how did you extract "01:13:19.775670462" from the number.

Comment: The question is, if your original precision was within the 24hr period of a day, and you convert the resulting long back to date again, do you get the same day? If so, then you're actually fine. If the answer is, it isn't precise enough. Then you need to review whether date is the correct sql type, as far as precision, in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are losing too much precision in your conversion to be able to go back the other way. You can get closer by using timestamps instead of dates.

Firstly your initial query was losing the time component completely:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
  + (1432550197431912935 - power(2, 60))/power(2, 44), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;

2013-07-09 01:13:19
```

... but even with that, converting back has lost way too much:

```
select ((to_date('2013-07-09 01:13:19','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  - date '1970-01-01') * power(2, 44)) + power(2, 60) from dual;

1432550197477589405
```

Which is closer than the 1432549301782839296 you got, but still quite a long way off.

Part of the problem is the precision of `DATE`, which is only to the second. If you use `TIMESTAMP` instead you can get quite close; you can see that the value to have is supposedly very precise:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
  + numtodsinterval((1432550197431912935 - power(2, 60))/power(2, 44), 'DAY')
from dual;

2013-07-09 01:13:18.775670462
```

Converting that back is complicated by timestamp arithmetic giving interval results, which you then have to manipulate to get back to a number, first as the original number of days:

```
select extract(day from int_val)
  + extract(hour from int_val) / 24
  + extract(minute from int_val) / (24 * 60)
  + extract(second from int_val) / (24 * 60 * 60)
from (
select to_timestamp('2013-07-09 01.13.18.775670462', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9')
  - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' as int_val from dual);

15895.0509117554451620370370370370370371
```

... and then with your power manipulation:

```
select ((extract(day from int_val)
    + extract(hour from int_val) / 24
    + extract(minute from int_val) / (24 * 60)
    + extract(second from int_val) / (24 * 60 * 60))
  * power(2, 44)) + power(2, 60)
as x
from (
select to_timestamp('2013-07-09 01.13.18.775670462', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9')
  - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' as int_val from dual);

1432550197431912935.09988554676148148148
```

Which is pretty darn close. You could trunc or round that to the nearest whole number.

---

Just looking at your numbers and the power manipulation each way shows that it seems to be within the precision Oracle can cope with:

```
select (1432550197431912935 - power(2, 60)) / power(2, 44)
from dual;

15895.050911755445156359201064333319664

select (15895.050911755445156359201064333319664 * power(2, 44)) + power(2, 60)
from dual;

1432550197431912935.000...
```

Even with a timestamp, you lose some of that, as that first value is going past the 9-digit fractional second limit. The part that represents the fractional seconds - once you've accounted for the 15895 hours etc. - is `.0000089776673785814232865555418862` of a day, which is `.77567046150943497195839881896768` seconds; the timestamp is rounding that to `.775670462`. So it's never going to be perfect.

That also leads one to wonder how the original number is being generated; it seems unlikely it actually represents a time down to that extreme precision, since it's below [yoctoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(time)). It isn't really clear if the 'precision' is actually an artefact of it being manipulated based on powers of 2, but it doesn't look very useful anyway. It's more common to use the Unix-style epoch date, counting seconds or sometimes milliseconds since the epoch date you're using anyway, if it has to be stored as a number at all. This design is... interesting.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have given maximum precision. Very well understood and thanks for your efforts and  time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query:

```
select     TO_CHAR(((TO_DATE ('09-JUL-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') -to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) + POWER(2,60) ) * POWER(2,44)) from dual
```

Comment: Can you please try SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'J')) FROM DUAL; query? I don't have Oracle access right now.